# How do I print all the words out in a Trie?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, ternary-search-tree

I have a **Ternary Search Tree** (**Trie**) and I want to print out all of the words in it.

How do I go about this using this current implementation that I have below?
I have a standard `put` method to add new words to the tree. I was attempting to print the words using an in-order traversal, but I'm unsure how exactly to complete the function.

```
class TST {
    private Node root;

    public void put(String key, int value) {
        root = put(root, key, value, 0);
    }

    private Node put(Node node, String key, int value, int index) {
        char c = key.charAt(index);

        if( node == null ){
            node = new Node(c);
        }

        if( c < node.character ){
            node.left = put(node.left, key, value, index);
        }else if( c > node.character ){
            node.right = put(node.right, key, value, index);
        }else if( index < key.length()-1 ){
            node.middle = put(node.middle, key, value, index+1);
        }else{
            node.value = value;
        }

        return node;
    }

    public Integer get(String key) {
        Node node = get(root, key, 0);

        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return node.value;
    }

    public Node get(Node node, String key, int index) {
        if(node == null) {
            return null;
        }

        char c = key.charAt(index);

        if (c < node.character) {
            return get(node.left, key, index);
        } else if (c > node.character) {
            return get(node.right, key, index);
        } else if(index < key.length() -1) {
            return get(node.middle, key, index);
        } else {
            return node;
        }
    }

    public void inorderTraversal(Node node) {
        System.out.print(node.character + ":" + node.value + " ");

        if(node.left != null) {
            inorderTraversal(node.left);
        }
        if(node.middle != null) {
            inorderTraversal(node.middle);
        }

        if(node.right != null) {
            inorderTraversal(node.right);
        }
    }

    public void traverse() {
        inorderTraversal(root);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TST tst = new TST();
        tst.put("This",3);
        tst.put("There",4);
        tst.put("Them",5);
        tst.put("High",6);
        System.out.println(tst.get("T"));
        tst.traverse();
    }
}

class Node {
    public char character;
    public Node left, right, middle;
    public int value;

    public Node(char character) {
        this.character = character;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, I hope you've took the small [tour] of SO already. What is the problem exactly ? See [ask]

Comment: Thanks :), I just want to be able to print out all the words that are stored in the tree I can print out the Nodes fine but not the words. Its supposed to be a fairly common interview question but I can't find out how to do so.

Comment: Okay so I added the Node and Main class here I enter in words to the tree each of the characters of these words are given a node and a value, I can print out all the characters fine but what I want is to print out the words that are in the tree. Heres a visualization for treis https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/TST.html

Comment: Ok, I read that one wrong... you need to concat your character in a collection until you reach the end. So that you can rebuild the value. If you want every values, you will need to remove a character each time you "go up" to add the next ones. PS: with a [mcve], I would probably have read your question with more attention ;)

Comment: I'll try in the future, first time asking a question here lol will bear that in mind for the future, do you have any idea how to implement it, I'm thinking of something like a DFS but am unsure?

Comment: Okay thanks will bear in mind for future posts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each node only stores a single character, you need to pass along a String (or StringBuilder, if you're trying to be efficient) representing the prefix defined by the path from the root when doing your traversal.

As per the definition of a ternary search tree, you should only append to this prefix when going to the middle node.

An example implementation:

```
public void inorderTraversal(Node node, String word) {
    // handle end of word
    if (node.value != 0) {
        System.out.println(word + node.character + ": " + node.value);
    }

    if(node.left != null) {
        inorderTraversal(node.left, word);
    }

    if (node.middle != null) {
        inorderTraversal(node.middle, word + node.character);
    }

    if(node.right != null) {
        inorderTraversal(node.right, word);
    }
}

public void traverse() {
    inorderTraversal(root, "");
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/WqxHX5).

It's also possible to store the String representing the full word at each node during construction, since you already have the complete word in your `put` method (if you're not worried about the memory usage).

---

Note that this / your code doesn't allow for mapping words to a 0 value - one way to deal with that is to use `Integer` instead of `int`, then you can use `!= null` to check for the end of a word.

Comment: Thanks a million, this was really annoying me :), could use values for that because the last letter of each word holds a value where other nodes that are in the middle of a sentence have the value of 0 or null in generic cases.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that xD